# Dynamically allocate memory in Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, memory-management

If I want to allocate a dynamic part of memory of an unknown size or rather size which will be known at runtime, after a user enters the number of megabytes he wants to be allocated , for example, what will the best way to do that? Is it calling "malloc" from C that is asking an OS to do so for me? Or is there a better way? **How is it usually done?**

Note that I don't want to reserve

Comment: call malloc or mmap, exactly like you would from C, or like a C compiler would do in the asm it generates from your C.  (Or `realloc` / `calloc` / `aligned_alloc` / whatever.)  The *best* way depends on what you're doing.

Comment: `malloc` is a function from the C library. If you do not want to link it to your program, you can use the underlying system call which is normally `sbrk` or `mmap`. But your question lacks from context to be an acceptable one on this site.

Comment: related non-Linux example: avr-libc (for bare-metal programs running on the 8-bit RISC AVR architecture) implements malloc [this way](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html).  See the "implementation details" section at the end for how the allocator works and manages its freelist.  You could certainly do something like this in user-space on Linux (on any architecture) *if* you wanted to implement your own allocator.  But normally there's no reason to do that, just call `aligned_alloc`.  Although normally any loop worth writing in asm for high perf avoids dynamic allocation.

Comment: i.e. the answer to "how is it usually done": not at all from asm.  Only write the truly performance-critical parts of your code in asm.  See for example `x264` or `ffmpeg` where most code is in C, and only a few SIMD or whatever functions are hand-written in asm.

Comment: At the time when we did write apps in assembly, PC-DOS was a single user system where you got all memory by default. So it wasn't a problem. Nowadays I would write the main program in C or something, setting up the environment and then **possibly** call some assembly for a *very* specialized task. Calling `malloc` from assembly is no faster than calling it from C, just more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way is to define static array as large as possible and write your own `malloc`/`free` subroutines. It is simple especially if there is no multithreading or other kind of shared usage of the allocated blocks. You keep the address of first empty block and in the beginning of each block is stored the size of block and address of next free block.

PS: allocated (reserved) blocks also contain block size as prefix. The address of next block is not used here and can be 0 as flag for "reserved" memory. More simple solution is to have only block size and flag free/used_block but in this way you have to scan multiple reserved blocks until reaching free block which is slower than a chain of only free blocks.

Comment: If you're going to implement your own malloc/free, you'd normally do it on top of `sbrk` and/or `mmap` system calls to get more memory from the OS when your free-list is empty.  With a giant static array, you can never return memory to the OS once it's been touched.  (Other than `munmap / mmap` on pages of your array.)

Comment: Honestly though, this isn't a bad answer for a "toy" program.  It's not a good design, but it is super-simple and probably easy to implement in asm for a beginner.  (It wasn't my downvote).  BTW, the details you describe would seem to require that deallocation functions provide the size of the block so it's different from the `malloc`/`free` API.

Comment: This is alternative way and depends on the OP's needs. But If someone don't like it and think it is not serious, let he (or she) thinks why the OP is writing program for Linux in assembly... `mmap ` is already mentioned in the comments above, I had to say something other not to repeat the same. About initial `mmap` / `munmap` array allocation - of course it can be done but if the needs for RAM are low (e.g. total 10-20MB) it can be statically reserved as well.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, you can repeat (and expand on) any / all good suggestions from comments.  It's actually encouraged to turn answer-comments into proper answers.  I only commented because the question is too vague to know what kind of answer is appropriate, but if you're going to post one, you should definitely mention `mmap` and `sbrk`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I started to write comment and then decided to post it as answer because: 1) It is one of the possible solutions, not best or recommended but it is also not recommeded to write in assembly under Linux; 2) Because it is too long for comment. You are right about `mmap` but tell it to comments under question - why they are not answers? In any way if the OP wants to learn assembly not to develop "serious" software, he may choose my solution instead of `mmap`.

Answer (score 1):

The mmap2 and brk system calls are the easiest way to do this in assembly. The mmap2 syscall is more difficult to use in assembly, but if you need a large amount of dynamically allocated memory, this is the way to go.
brk is easy to use, it works by moving the "program break" (the boundary of your program's memory space) effectively allocating more memory for your program. This is the way to go if you need a small amount of dynamic memory (e.g. less than a full page).

Comment: malloc is a c library function rather than a system call. Malloc basically wraps both brk and mmap2 syscalls, but it also does keeps internal information about the memory that has been allocated for use in later malloc calls or free calls. You can only use malloc if you like with the c library.

Comment: but it's simpler and not much, if at all, overhead to use it from assemlby, no?

Comment: `malloc` would be simplest. There is no performance overhead to using it it assembly versus C - they are both straight function calls. There could of course be overhead relative to some other bespoke allocation strategy. If you are writing a lot in assembly for some reason it will be very useful to link against and use the C library to avoid re-inventing the wheel whenever you want a random utility function.

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do. I wouldn't say that its simpler than brk, invoking a brk syscall or calling malloc are similar and even have similer arguments and return values, the internal functionality of malloc is certainly more complex. As for overhead, thats a matter of your projects requirements. Linking with libc brings overhead with it, but if you need libc anyway then it probably makes sense to just use malloc.

Comment: `malloc` is as simple as it gets: you `call` `malloc` with 1 argument in `rdi` and get your memory region back. `brk` is already more complex because you have to setup a system call, but mostly because it doesn't allow you dynamically allocate and free memory: it just gives you a rough tool to extend the process data segment. On top of that you have to implement your dynamic allocation scheme (i.e., reinvent a simple form of malloc). Also, depending on the OS and various other factors, you might only be able to access a small fraction of the available virtual memory space through brk.

Comment: Of course `malloc` has lots of internal complexity, but who cares?

Comment: One could argue though that `mmap` is about as simple as `malloc` - with the restriction that you have to ask for memory in granules of the page size of 4K.

Comment: Usually the kind of person that cares is the same kind of person that programs in assembly. If you don't care, thats fine, but other people might and that's fine too. We are here for answers to technical issues, not advice on what we should care about.

Comment: Well we are trying to answer the OP's quesiton, and he said "best" and then he left it pretty vague. I think a reasonable person would not care about the internal complexity of the function they are calling: they should care mostly about the complexity and performance of using themselves. As soon as you are using Linux, you are already using a massively complex system, even in "programming in assembly". I program in assembly I could care less about the internal complexity of the functions they call: I care do they do their job and do they do it quickly.

Comment: To be that's a reasonable behavior and I would assume it by default when someone asks a question about what's "best". If you have some very weird requirement like "I care about how many lines of code it takes to implement the opaque function I am calling", then they should _say it_ - because it's an unusual assumption (you'll also have to specify what implementation, etc, since they will all vary a lot). Anyway your first sentence is very clear: you claim the _easiest way_ to allocate is `brk()` or `mmap` - that's explicitly about ease-of-use, not "internal complexity of malloc".

Comment: I think you could make a reasonable argument about _performance_ though! For example, you say that calling the general purpose `malloc` is likely to be slower than a very simple allocator - if you use case is suitable simple. You still need to build an allocator though: calling `brk()` (I think you are more likely to actually use `sbrk()`) or `mmap` is going to be _slower_ in general than `malloc` since it's a system call every time. So for performance you have to implement some kind of allocator on top of it.

Comment: I would assume that any assembly programmer is concerned about performance. However, since best is vague, I don't assign value to the possible methods, I just give the information I have, which is why I gave information about all 3 (malloc, brk, and mmap2). I don't have performance numbers, and there are cases I'm sure where malloc is faster, and cases where plain mmap2 or brk will be faster, all depends on the usage.

Comment: Also note, that the syscall is brk (in Linux). sbrk is a libc function in Linux. On other systems (FreeBSD if I recall correctly) may have an sbrk syscall, but Linux does not.